# unable to send emails django-helpdesk

Tags: django, email

I am using django-helpdesk for ticketing system.
its working fine but i am not able to send emails. i am testing this on my localhost.

while i submit a ticket, its getting submitted properly but submitter is not getting any email for newly created ticket.

i added new queue and provided details like E-Mail Address, E-Mail Box Type, E-Mail Hostname, E-Mail Port, Use SSL for E-Mail=False, E-Mail Username, E-Mail Password, IMAP Folder, E-Mail Check Interval properly.
but emails not getting sent.

then i removed all off above from queue and added settings like

```
QUEUE_EMAIL_BOX_TYPE = IMAP
QUEUE_EMAIL_BOX_SSL = True
QUEUE_EMAIL_BOX_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
QUEUE_EMAIL_BOX_USER = 'email'
QUEUE_EMAIL_BOX_PASSWORD = 'pwd'
```

but still its not working.

am i missing any settings? please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

`QUEUE_EMAIL_BOX` settings are not for sending emails, but for receiving them. Configuration for sending emails goes into standard email settings from django.

If you're using [SMTP backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/#smtp-backend) (this is default), configuration should be:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'pwd'
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

Comment: I used exactly the same settings above. But its not working.